# Execute stored procedure with table values as parameter

Tags: t-sql

I create own table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ObjectsList] AS TABLE(
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [Id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

and when I want to pass this Type as parameter like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData](@DataIds ObjectsList READONLY)
```

how should I pass it in
EXEC GetData ????

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**[Look at this](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#tableparam)**

You can find an example

```
DECLARE @data ObjectList
INSERT @data (Id) VALUES (1)
EXEC GetData @data
```

Answer (score 1):

To populate @data by using a SELECT statement:

```
DECLARE @data ObjectList

INSERT @data (Id)
SELECT
  Id
FROM
  <someDB>.<someSchema>.<someTable>
  JOIN ... etc 
WHERE
  ... etc

EXEC GetData @data
```